# Gráficos de porcentagem em R

Tags: r, gráfico

Olá, preciso  fazer um gráfico de barras com histórico de porcentagem de clientes que compraram o produto ao longo dos anos de 2012 a 2022. No eixo x deve conter os anos e no eixo y as porcentagens. Na coluna cliente é sinalizado se ele comprou naquele ano 1 pra sim e 0 pra não.

```
Tabela1<- filtrar(dados, Clientes==1, Ano_Compra=> 2012)
Numerador <- (Tabela1$Clientes)
Denominador <- dados$Clientes)
Total_p<- round (sum(Numerador/(Denominador)*100,1)
```

Comment: Benvinda ao StackOverflow em português! Sua pergunta está ampla, pocentagem sobre o mês, ano? Qual linguagem está desenvolvendo sua solução? Pode colocar o que tentou para que alguém possa ajudar a encontrar a solução?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: `filtrar` não é uma função do R. Pode ser `subset(dados, Clientes==1 & Ano_Compra => 2012)`.

Comment: Fiz igual a esse código, mas não consegui colocar as porcentagens em cima das barras, sabem como eu faço isso? Tentei o geom_text mas não consegui

ggplot(subset(dados, Clientes == 1), aes(Ano_Compra)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop..), fill = "skyblue") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2012:2022, labels = 2012:2022) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)

Answer (score 1):

Aqui vão duas maneiras de traçar gráficos de barras a partir de variáveis binárias.

### R base

Primeiro calculam-se os totais com `tapply`, a seguir transformam-se em porcentagens.
Quanto ao gráfico, o eixo dos y vai ser traçado manualmente. A escala é formatada, chama-se `barplot` e o eixo no fim.

```r
totais <- with(dados, tapply(Clientes, Ano_Compra, FUN = sum))
porc <- 100*totais/sum(totais)
y_axis <- seq(0, max(porc) + 1L, by = 2.5)
barplot(porc, yaxt = "n", ylim = c(0, max(porc) + 1L))
axis(2, at = y_axis, labels = paste0(y_axis, "%"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Pacote `ggplot2`

A base `dados` é filtrada com `subset` para se ficar só com as linhas de compra 1, a contagem dessas linhas é feita pelo `geom_bar`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(subset(dados, Clientes == 1), aes(Ano_Compra)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop..), fill = "skyblue") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2012:2022, labels = 2012:2022) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

### Dados de teste

```r
set.seed(2022)
n <- 4000
Ano_Compra <- sample(2012:2022, n, replace = TRUE)
Clientes <- rbinom(n, 1, 0.5)
dados <- data.frame(Ano_Compra, Clientes)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Se [utiliza uma resposta na pergunta seguinte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/547317/como-inserir-porcentagem-no-gr%c3%a1fico-em-r), deve ao menos **aceitar a resposta**.